# What's the most accurate translation of Sneedronningen, a.k.a The Snow Queen?

Tags: translation, fairy-tales

What's the most accurate translation of [Sneedronningen](https://da.wikisource.org/wiki/Sneedronningen), a.k.a The Snow Queen? I'm seeing conflicting details in the translations I've seen. But it seems that versions which call the mirror-maker the actual Devil are more accurate than ones that don't...

TVTropes [reports](https://tvtropes.org/Literature/TheSnowQueen) that

> - [AnimateInanimateObject](https://tvtropes.org/Main/AnimateInanimateObject):
>   The mirror. It is sentient, and although the devils have to move it
>   around, it manages to laugh so loudly that it animates itself.

Referring to this, apparently:

> da zittrede Speilet saa frygteligt i sit Griin, at det foer dem ud af
> Hænderne og styrtede ned mod Jorden

I haven't found any translations that say that the mirror is *laughing*, specifically?

The [Hans Lien Brækstad](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Fairy_tales_and_stories_(Andersen,_Tegner)/The_Snow_Queen) translation comes closest, but it's the demons who carry the mirror that are laughing, not the mirror itself?

> The higher they flew with the mirror the more distorted and ridiculous
> the reflections became, till they could scarcely hold it for laughter.

While the [Walker translation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Fairy_tales_from_Hans_Christian_Andersen_(Walker)/The_Snow_Queen) has:

> but the higher they flew, the more it grinned, so much so that they could hardly hold it